# Center objects with particle system

Tags: objects, particles, faces, groups

how can i center a group of objects individually in the center of every face of the plane, with a random order in all over the plane, with particle system?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

- Emit all 'particles' in the first frame
- Set emit from faces
- Grid
  . let resolution match you subdivision
- assign the group and pick whole group or let blender pick random group member

[image]

[image]